# How to BREAK on with multiples tables

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

For example there are three tables that are linked. I know you can use break on to get unique values for a column when using a select statement. My question is how can I use break on with multiple tables joined in a select statement. This is the code I have now.

```
CLEAR BREAKS
BREAK ON STR.STR_NUM SKIP 1 ON STR.STR_QTY SKIP 1

SELECT STR.STR_NUM, STR.STR_QTY, SUPP.SUPP_ID,SUPP.SUPP_COMP
FROM STR
INNER JOIN SUPPSTR 
ON STR.STR_NUM = SUPPSTR.STR_NUM 
INNER JOIN SUPP
ON SUPP.SUPP_ID = SUPPSTR.SUPP_ID    
ORDER BY STR.STR_NUM,STR.STR_QTY,SUPP.SUPP_ID ASC;
```

This gives me multiple values of STR_NUM matched with each QTY and COMP of each. However I don't want duplicates of STR_NUM and STR_QTY(only SUPP_ID and SUPP_COMP), which I am trying to accomplish with BREAK on but it's not working.

I can only seem to use Break on with one table.

For example I will get an output like this:

```
STR_NUM   STR_QTY   SUPP_ID  SUPP_COMP
1001      120       101       AA
1001      120       102       AB
1001      120       103       AC
1002      300       101       AA
1002      300       102       AB
1002      300       103       AC
1002      300       104       AD
1003      100       101       AA
1003      100       102       AB
1003      100       103       AC
1004      50        101       AA
1004      50        102       AB
```

But what I want is something like this:

```
STR_NUM   STR_QTY   SUPP_ID  SUPP_COMP
1001      120       101       AA
                    102       AB
                    103       AC

1002      300       101       AA
                    102       AB
                    103       AC
                    104       AD

1003      100       101       AA  
                    102       AB
                    103       AC
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
22:24:25 (21)HR@sandbox> select * from (select department_id, job_id, employee_id from employees order by 1,2,3) where rownum < 15;

DEPARTMENT_ID JOB_ID     EMPLOYEE_ID
------------- ---------- -----------
           10 AD_ASST            200
           20 MK_MAN             201
           20 MK_REP             202
           30 PU_CLERK           115
           30 PU_CLERK           116
           30 PU_CLERK           117
           30 PU_CLERK           118
           30 PU_CLERK           119
           30 PU_MAN             114
           40 HR_REP             203
           50 SH_CLERK           180
           50 SH_CLERK           181
           50 SH_CLERK           182
           50 SH_CLERK           183

14 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
22:24:49 (21)HR@sandbox> break on department_id on job_id
22:24:55 (21)HR@sandbox> /

DEPARTMENT_ID JOB_ID     EMPLOYEE_ID
------------- ---------- -----------
           10 AD_ASST            200
           20 MK_MAN             201
              MK_REP             202
           30 PU_CLERK           115
                                 116
                                 117
                                 118
                                 119
              PU_MAN             114
           40 HR_REP             203
           50 SH_CLERK           180
                                 181
                                 182
                                 183

14 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.04
```

And yeah, this has nothing to do with amount of tables in query. BREAK is not an sql but sqlplus operator which only processes query output and is not impacted by the query details.  Multi-table example:

```
22:31:07 (21)HR@sandbox> break
break on department_name nodup
          on job_id nodup

22:31:15 (21)HR@sandbox> l
  1  select * from (
  2  select d.department_name, e.job_id, e.employee_id
  3    from employees e join departments d using(department_id)
  4   order by 1,2,3
  5* ) where rownum < 15
22:31:15 (21)HR@sandbox> /

DEPARTMENT_NAME                JOB_ID     EMPLOYEE_ID
------------------------------ ---------- -----------
Accounting                     AC_ACCOUNT         206
                               AC_MGR             205
Administration                 AD_ASST            200
Executive                      AD_PRES            100
                               AD_VP              101
                                                  102
Finance                        FI_ACCOUNT         109
                                                  110
                                                  111
                                                  112
                                                  113
                               FI_MGR             108
Human Resources                HR_REP             203
IT                             IT_PROG            103

14 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.10
```